# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setPaths')

Tags: highcharts

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setPaths')
B.step
D:/velocis_vsmart/React/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-3d.js:578

Getting this issue in highcharts in reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6NuA.png)

Comment: Hi, could you please check your Highcharts version? It seems to be a bug from the v7 which is already fixed: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13804

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using a compatible version of Highcharts and the Highcharts 3D module and ensure that you have properly initialized and configured Highcharts in your React component.
Also verify that the data you are trying to plot with Highcharts is valid and correctly formatted. Highcharts may throw errors if the data is not in the expected format.
Wrap your Highcharts code in a try-catch block to handle any exceptions and log more detailed error information.
Example try-catch block:

```
try {
  // Write your code here
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Highcharts Error:', error);
}
```